# Iterate over properties of a struct and check if they are equal to the properties of other value of the same type

Tags: swift

Let's say I have a struct containing a list of scalar properties:

```
struct SomeGeometricProps {
    var frame: CGRect
    var transform: CGAffineTransform
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat
    var count: Int
    var someDouble: Double
    // ...and a lot of other properties
}
```

Now, I want to add conformance to `Equatable`, but I don't want to hard-code the comparison of each property, because 1) it will lead to a lot of spaghetti-code, 2) in case somebody will add a new property this code will break if they will forget to add it to the `==` method. So, I try the following:

```
extension SomeGeometricProps: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: SomeGeometricProps, rhs: SomeGeometricProps) -> Bool {
        let lhsProperties = Mirror(reflecting: lhs).children
            .compactMap { $0.label != nil ? $0 : nil }
            .sorted { $0.label! < $1.label! }
            .compactMap { $0.value as? Equatable }
        let rhsProperties = Mirror(reflecting: rhs).children
            .compactMap { $0.label != nil ? $0 : nil }
            .sorted { $0.label! < $1.label! }
            .compactMap { $0.value as? Equatable }
        return zip(lhsProperties, rhsProperties).reduce(true) { $0 && $1.0 == $1.1 }
    }
}
```

but it does not compile, because `Protocol 'Equatable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements` i.e. I can't make an array of `Equatable` properties of my type.
I know I can write type-erased struct conforming to `Equatable`, but for me it looks like an overhead assuming all I need is just to test a list of properties for equality.

Is there any way of doing it dynamically?

Comment: Which one of your properties does not conform to Equatable? Based on the one you've included you should be able to just mark your struct as conforming as Equatable and the compiler will do the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recent versions of swift, if all the properties of a struct are equatable, you can make the struct `Equatable` without having to implement the `==` function.

In your case, all of your properties *are* `Equatable`, so you can just declare the struct as `Equatable` and you're done.

If the vast majority of your properties are `Equatable` it might be easier to add "equatability" to those properties.